# Identifying corrupt records within avro file

Tags: apache-spark, avro

I have an avro file which has corruption within it; when trying to read it with apache Spark I get an "Invalid Sync" error. If possible I want to repair the corrupted block, but certainly at the very least view the data within the corrupt block.

I can repair the file using avro-tools, however I believe 200 records are going missing (200 lines are missing from the file after repair).

I have identified the corrupt block number (359), and manually identified the syncronisation marker.

I know that if I can find the lines which contain the 359th and 360th sync marker, the data I care about is between those markers. However I can't find a tool that can find the Nth occurence of a hexadecimal string within a file.

I'm looking for ways that at least view the corrupt data so that I can identify whether any of it is recoverable.